# скачать фаил хранимый и на сервере и в базе данных mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Я использую plugin, который загружает файлы и инфоромацию о них на сервер. Файлы можно скачать через админку этого плагина, все работает. Я захотел доработать его, что бы файлы еще можно было скачать и со стороны посетителей и столкнулся с такой проблемой:

Я знаю, что фалы можно хранить либо в базе данных, либо на сервере. Обычно на сервере бывают сами файлы, а в базе названия. Как получить файлы я знаю, НО в этом plugin'е как я понимаю на сервере хранятся не полные файлы (т.к скачивая их на прямую пишут что они повреждены) а в базе лежит кусочек этих файлов 32B BLOB. Как в таком случае мне скачать полный файл? :

[image: Вот как выглядет база]

Comment: Для начала найти код, который эти файлы сохраняет, что бы понять что и где лежит. Может на сервере файл шифрован а в БД лежит ключ для расшифровки. А может еще что нибудь

Comment: да, действительно, используют эти private i public key для шифровки файлов...

Comment: ну ответ думаю очевиден: написать скрипт который их расшифрует перед передачей на клиента

Comment: да, спасибо за подсказку, хотя бы понял в чем дело и что есть такая возможность :) буду пытаться как то расшифровать :(